# kilowatt meter is using a proportional voltage x amps to create watts problems

Tags: power, power-engineering

So if a kilowatt meter is using a proportional voltage x amps to create watts used then in a situation where. 1. A pump motor using lets say 220v  single ph is running while or starts running during a time of low voltage, doesn't the current draw thru the kilowatt meter read the higher current draw from the motor being run in these conditions. Most EEE would say that the kilowatt meter is proportional to the input voltages and the meter would not run any faster due to the low voltage or lower voltages and if that were true then why  do the kilowatts used vary so much when the behavior of the pump motor does not change.

Comment: Power is the average of the voltage waveform multiplied by the current waveform irrespective of load. Other than that I can't offer anything more because your question appears to be fairly undecipherable.

Comment: Rather than scribbling madly about things you don't understand (evidently while sleep-deprived or otherwise impaired) try describing your actual system behavior and you problem with the actual system behavior. "Power use on pump varies" - perhaps the level of the items being pumped also varies, varying the power required, mystery solved, no veering off into cockamamie-land.

Comment: So that you know I am not under the influence of anything I am not a EEE but an uneducated physical engineer of sorts in the HVAC industry. And lets say I am not a scholar of the format or correct terminology, but I am not misrepresenting my findings by asking this.

Answer (score 3):

A meter that has a disk that can run faster or slower is a kilowatt-hour meter not a kilowatt meter. The speed of the disk (revolutions per second) is proportional to power (watts or joules per second) the total number of revolutions over a period of time is proportional to energy (kilowatt-hours or joules). What we pay for when we "use" electrical power is energy (kilowatt-hours) not power (kilowatts).

It is true that voltage a variation does not cause an AC induction motor to have much speed or power variation, but it does cause a small speed variation and the power variation caused with a pump is the speed variation cubed.

The power required to drive a pump is proportional to the rate of flow multiplied by the pressure multiplied by density divided by efficiency. A change in anything that affects flow pressure density or efficiency will cause the power to vary.